# PHP 7.0 if else

Tags: php, if

```
<?php
    $a = 100;
    if ($a > 49) {
        $b = $a*$a;
        echo ($b);
    }
    if ($a > 10 and $a <30) {
        echo '0';
    }
    else {
        echo "Ошибка";
    }
?>
```

Почему при задании переменной $a значения больше 49 выводится не только квадрат значения этой переменной, но и "ошибка", которая описана в else?

Comment: `$a = 100; echo ($a > 49) ? $b = $a * $a : (($a > 10 && $a < 30) ? 0 : 'Ошибка');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас получается два условия, во второй проверке используйте if else

```
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a больше, чем b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a равен b";
} else {
    echo "a меньше, чем b";
}
```

[manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: elseif однако...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $a = 100;
    if ($a > 49) {
        $b = $a*$a;
        echo ($b);
    } elseif ($a > 10 and $a <30) {
        echo '0';
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что после выполнения первого условия выполняется вторая конструкция if-else. Надо так:

```
    $a = 100;
    if ($a > 49) {
        $b = $a*$a;
        echo ($b);
    }
    elseif($a>10&&$a<30) {
        echo '0';
    }
    else {
        echo "Ошибка";
    }
```